# Using multiple sql JOINS in python

Tags: python, mysql

Here is my code:

```
query="SELECT c.name AS client_name, s.name AS store_name, dd.mac_address AS mac_address "\
               "FROM d2_clients AS c "\
               "JOIN d2_stores AS s "\
               "ON c.name = s.client_name "\
               "JOIN d2_data_feeds AS dd "\
               "ON s.metric_key = dd.metric_key "\
               "WHERE s.active = 1 "\
               "GROUP BY 1,2,3 "

return msql.executeQueryAsDict(query,self.connection)
```

My 2nd join never works and always returns null entries. The exact same query runs fine on mysqlpro client.

Also, eliminating the 2nd join makes it work again. Wondering whats the right syntax? Thought this should work.

Comment: oh thats just the python mysql connector; don't worry about that.

Comment: yes thats exactly right. Format for 2nd join must be wrong.

Comment: What I would do is `print(query)` and see what the actual query looks that is being sent to your mysql server..